# Finding the absolute value of a Byte variable in Kotlin or Java?

Tags: java, kotlin, jvm, byte

Why isn't there any function in the standard library of Kotlin/Java for taking the absolute value of a Byte/byte variable? I'm I missing something?

**Math.abs()** is only defined for int, long, double and float.

For context: in the audio world you can run easily into byte arrays representing the amplitude. I'm interested in calculating the average of the absolute values of a byte array. For e.g see this [listener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener) related to Visualizer in Android.

I know I can cast it to an integer and take the absolute value of that, but I would still be interested why is this not predefined.

Comment: Because nobody bothers to do math on bytes; they're pretty universally used for stored data only.

Comment: It isn't defined for `short` either

Comment: @LouisWasserman well in the audio world you run into byte arrays because samples can be represented in bytes depending on the encoding.

Comment: You can always use the version that takes an `int` and the result to `byte`. That will give incorrect results for -128 though, as 128 cast to `byte` is -128. However, the same is true for `Integer.MIN_VALUE` - it's even documented.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Unless there is a developer of the Kotlin language around nobody can really answer why there is no Math.abs that accepts a byte. If your question is how to do Math.abs on a byte we could potentially answer that, but I'm not sure if that's what you are asking.

Comment: Interesting… I started to draft an Answer saying that a `Byte`/`byte` in Java is neither positive nor negative. But then I checked the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/). Section [4.2.1. *Integral Types and Values*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1) of the spec says explicitly that a `byte` is a number in the range of -128 to 127, inclusive. So this is a curious Question, as logically there should indeed be a `Math.abs( byte )` and `Math.abs( short )` as there is a `abs` method for `int`, `long`, `float`, and `double`.

Comment: @BasilBourque the only integral type that is “neither positive nor negative” is `boolean`. There is a type that is never negative, `char`, but that doesn’t imply that it is “neither positive nor negative”, as a `char` value is still either zero or positive. And Java doesn’t mind if you write `Math.abs('A')` or even a statement like `if('x' < 0) System.out.println("impossible");`. That’s not the point.

Comment: @Holger But there's the rub. Intuitively, I would not think of a "byte" type as being an integral type. I would think of a "byte" type as a merely an ordered collection of bits, without interpretation as a number.

Comment: @BasilBourque really? What is it then, what you would think of a `byte`, if not an integral type? Both meanings (“built-in type” and “integer type”) fit perfectly.

Comment: @Holger As an ordered collection of bits, a "byte" type in my mind would not be negative nor positive, nor would it makes sense to ask for absolute value. But the point here on this page is that my intuitive sense of a byte is *not* the definition of the `byte`/`Byte` type in Java. Clearly, the designers of Java intended `byte`/`Byte` to be a shorter `short`/`Short`, an 8-bit signed number, as a smaller member of the short-int-long family. Hence the validity of this page’s Question: Why is `byte` defined as an integral type yet not treated as an integer when it comes to `abs` methods, etc.?

Comment: @BasilBourque that’s a valid interpretation when you have graphic data stored in a byte array, but you could say similar things about the `int` array encoding (a)rgb data. Likewise, a byte sequence containing encoded characters can be seen as non-numeric. However, the OP mentions audio data, where treating bytes as the signed values, as they are defined in Java, is perfectly valid. And I answered that question, taking the overall language design into account. `byte` and `short` are smaller numbers (and, in fact, `char` too, for that matter), but their arithmetic operations always use `int`.

Comment: @BasilBourque Suppose that Java did provide a `static byte Math.abs(byte a)` method. Given that you have already mentioned that _"the spec says explicitly that a byte is a number in the range of -128 to 127, inclusive"_, what should that method return as the absolute value of -128?

Comment: @skomisa Oh, I don't know. Maybe the same thing it does for [`Math.abs( int )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#abs(int)) and [`Math.abs( long )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#abs(long))? To quote the Javadoc:  *“Note that if the argument is equal to the value of Integer.MIN_VALUE, the most negative representable int value, the result is that same value, which is negative. In contrast, the absExact(int) method throws an ArithmeticException for this value.”*

Comment: @BasilBourque So for -128, a `byte` implementation of `abs()` would return -128 (or even +127 as proposed in an answer below!), while the `int` implementation returns +128. That is a disaster waiting to happen. Regardless of that though, the widening/promotion for `byte`, described in Holger's answer below, explains why it is entirely appropriate that there is no `byte` implementation of `abs()` in **java.lang.Math**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operations in `java.lang.Math` are in line with all other arithmetic operations in Java. Integer operations always work in either, 64 bit `long` or 32 bit `int`.

As stated in [JLS, §4.2.2. Integer Operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.2-200)

> If an integer operator other than a shift operator has at least one operand of type `long`, then the operation is carried out using 64-bit precision, and the result of the numerical operator is of type `long`. If the other operand is not `long`, it is first widened ([§5.1.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.5)) to type `long` by numeric promotion ([§5.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6)).
>
> Otherwise, the operation is carried out using 32-bit precision, and the result of the numerical operator is of type `int`. If either operand is not an `int`, it is first widened to type `int` by numeric promotion.

In other words, not even the following, equivalent to `abs`, would compile:

```java
byte a = 42, absA = a < 0? -a: a;
```

as the numeric operation `-a` will promote `a` to `int` before negating.

It’s important that a cast of the result to `byte` would not be a lossless operation here. The `byte` datatype has a value range from `-128` to `+127`, so if the value is `-128`, its absolute value `+128` is outside the byte value range and a cast to `byte` would cause an overflow to `-127`.

Therefore, to have a correct and efficient calculation, you should do as always in Java when it comes to `byte`, `short`, or `char` calculations, calculate everything using `int` and only cast the final result back to your data type. When you want to calculate the average, you have to calculate the sum using `int` anyway (or even `long` if you have more than 16777215 array elements).

```java
byte[] array // e.g. test case: = { 1, -1, -128, 127 };

int sum = 0;
for(byte b: array) sum += Math.abs(b);
int average = sum/array.length;
// if you really need a byte result
byte byteAverage = average == 128? 127: (byte)average;
```

I don’t know about Kotlin, but in Java, the automatic promotion to `int` also works if the operand is of type `Byte`, so you don’t need to “cast it to an integer” to call `Math.abs(int)`. You only have to deal with the fact that the result will be an `int`, as with all arithmetic operations on `byte`, `short`, `char`, or their wrapper types.

Answer (score 0):

In java `byte` is signed between -128 and 127, corresponding as (unsigned) int: `0xFF & b` between 128 .. 255, and 0 .. 127.

`Math.abs` is irrelevant here as probably unsigned byte values are assumed.

```
int[] bytesToInt(byte[] bs) {
    int[] is = new int[bs.length];
    Arrays.fill(is, i -> bs[i] & 0xFF);
    return is;
}

byte byteAbs(byte b) {
    return b >= 0? b : b == -128? 127 : -b;
}
```

`byteAbs` - given for completeness - reduces the range to 7 bits, and has the artefact that -128 maps to 127, as there is no 128.